# How to link a custom framework or library against an iOS executable/binary file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unix, gcc

First of all, this is for enterprise ad-hoc apps, not for submitting to the app store.

I have created a framework(could also be a static library) that contains some categories. I would like to use some command line tool to link this against an executable file in an ipa file. Create a combined/modified executable file. Then re-sign and package the app to modify some of its behavior. Is this possible? The bottom line is, sometimes I don't have the source code and can't build this in xcode. All I have is an ipa file.

My thought is to tell the dynamic linker to load it(DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES) but I don't know the exact command. Can someone provide me some details?